# Yarn removing dependencies when I add a package

Tags: javascript, typescript, yarnpkg

When I install dependencies with `yarn add lambda-warmer` yarn removes dependencies in my yarn.lock that aren't related to that package.

[image]

When running `yarn install --force` it will also have the same result, however `yarn install` does not.

Answer (score 1):

The issue stemmed from something being messed up in the yarn cache

`yarn cache clean`

resolved the error.